# Navigation Bar Changes Not Taking Effect at Runtime (Swift/XCode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm following a tutorial from Udemy.com for a to-do list app in Swift and I'm trying to change the navigation bar background color and text.  As you see here in this screenshot, the previewed changes are only showing in the Table View, not the Navigation Controller where I'm trying to change them.  Then when I run the app, the changes are nowhere to be seen.  I've done these changes entirely within the storyboard, with a few list values hardcoded in.  I can't continue until I can make the "+" button appear at runtime so I can let users add to the list.  Any idea what's wrong?  I'd rather not have to do it with code if I can avoid it.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the settings you have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the exact same tutorial as you and have created the same app. I ran into the same problem as you too.

After doing some research I was able to fix the problem. I believe it has to do with the fact that the way the navigation bar is styled changed in iOS 13. Particularly with the way that Large Titles work.

However, I have found that it is only possible with code. The Navigation Controller in the storyboard does not display the background colour for Large Titles even when it is set, so it still won't look right in the storyboard even when it is fixed. However, when you run the app, it should display correctly.

To fix the problem, I inserted the following code into the viewWillAppear() method in my View Controller:

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

Please let me know if this fixes it for you or if you come across any other problems.

Comment: This allows me to make changes to the runtime appearance.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit: Your solution did allow me to change the styling, but I found out that the reason I needed a workaround in the first place was because I had "Prefers Large Titles" checked as you can see in the answer I submitted below.  Thanks for the help!  I'll keep yours in mind in case I need that box checked.

Comment: Ah, okay. I assumed that you had intentionally set the “Prefers Large Titles” option. Later on in the tutorial they will be selecting that box, so you might find you need the code for then. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, this could be a bug with current XCode, but having this "Prefers Large Titles" option checked for the navigation bar is what is preventing the changes from being visible in the preview as well as from taking effect at runtime. [image]

Having it unchecked leaves it free to work in the preview and at runtime as intended in the tutorial with no problems.

[image]